# Azure components for photo / video content management

Tags: azure, content-management

I am evaluating Windows Azure for my photo / video management software which will have functionality of 
1) uploading the photos / videos, Tagging, album creation etc
2) Live streaming of content from server
3) Download of content from server.

CDN and AppFabric Cache will definitely be helpful here. Can anyone please let me know if there are some built in components / off the shelf components / specific design patterns of Azure which can facilitate the fast development e.g. if there is something else which can help in fast streaming of content, it will definitely be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As you've noted, the CDN and caching will definitelly help you. However I would mostly look at the CDN. I would use caching for relatively small chunks of data (such as any data-base driven lists of details, i.e. list of cities, or countries), or a slowly-changing data. I would not put large media content in AppFabric Cache.

As for leveraging blobs/CDN for streaming, you may want to check [this example](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/streamingazure).

**UPDATE**

Well, will you have some photo/video manipulation on server side? Or what people (users or admins) upload, that is served to the users?

If not, than there is nothing additional.

If you, however will have some image,video processing on the server side I suggest that you split your app into a WebRole (for users upload/download/stream) and a Worker Role (for processing). You can check out [this lab](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/WAZPlatformTrainingCourse_IntroToWindowsAzureLabVS2010) to get understanding of how to decouple web from worker role and how to submit work items to the worker.

The reason to have separate worker role for processing is to be able to independenatly scale either web or worker on demand.

Comment: Thanks Astaykov. I understand. Do you see any design patterns or any other component that could be of any help.